# How to repair mattress tufting buttons

Tags: sewing

Our dog ripped out a number of loosely threaded tufting buttons from our mattress and I'm looking for advice on how to repair or replace them.

This is the loop that attaches them to the mattress:

[image: Tufting loop/endpoint?]

This is what the intact "button" looks like:
[image: Intact tufting button]

I figured I would need a circle template to sew around and then finally attach it to the loop. I'm uncertain about how I would remove the template after I form a circle around it, or how I would finally attach it.

Would it be simpler to do it in place around the hook with a curved sewing needle?

Comment: Is the button just yarn or is there a cloth disk inside it? Even if the existing buttons are just yarn, any reason not to use a cloth disk inside to help make it (and leave it in)?

Comment: It appears to be just yarn threaded through the hoop in the centre. I suppose there's no reason I couldn't use a cotton disk as I'm just trying to pad the plastic rather that restore it to how it used to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think of the wrong kind of template. Instead of a disk (paper, plastic, metal), think of a bent wire (not closed / welded; the ends should overlap). You sew the button around it and through the middle piece, until you get the desired shape / size. Then you just remove the wire carefully.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, I'll attempt with a paperclip or similar